# Bind Gridview with Static Object values using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

```
Primary Number   Code           Secondary Number    Facility

(textbox)       (Dropdownlist)  (Textbox)Read-Only  (Textbox)Read-Only
 A1              B1              C1                  D1
 A1              B2              C1                  D1
```

The above is a Gridview control which has 4 columns.

Gridview will not be binding with Database. Data should be populated to Gridview from Static Objects.

Column1 (Primary Number) : The default value of this column should be taken from a pre-defined Static Object which holds some values.

Column2 (Code) : Value can be selected from the dropdownlist; the list of valies should be pre-defined in any Static object

Column3 (Secondary Number) : Based on the selection of col2(Code), this column value should be populated

Column4 (Facility) : Based on the selection of col2(Code), this column value also should be populated

Column 3 & 4 have relationship with Column 2.

The above all are the requirements of this project. Please help on implementing it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is somewhat confusing. Can i suggest reviewing it and being a little more clear?

Comment: Hi- Are my requirements clear now? May I please get some help on this?

Comment: what have you done so far? We won't just supply you with a working project code. You need to attempt it properly first, then show what you have tried to do.

Comment: additionally, is this winforms, asp.net, wpf etc. each work slightly differently  so its helpful to know (update tag accordingly)

Comment: I'm developing this as a web application using asp.net. I'm not expecting source code here. These are the requirements. To satisfy this, how should I approach since there is no DB objects , I have to handle data with non-DB objects and also I'm very new to it. So, please guide me how should I frame the project structure.

Comment: you have pretty much outlined what you need to do, next step is to go ahead and try to implement it yourself in some fashion. If it what you attempt doesnt work the way you want it, return here with the code and we can have a look.